# Are there any best practices what Controller methods should return?

Tags: spring, controller

For example, should controller return updated entity after update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fit into your question we can set the "best practices" in the range of the verbs. What is the best option to return for each verb?

I'm going to use the book [RESTful Web Services](https://learning.oreilly.com/library/view/restful-web-services/9780596529260/) (Chapter 4) to answer your question.

This is textual iformation from the book, none of the following words are mine.

**GET**

> The server sends back a representation in the response entity-body.

**POST**

> Response of POST request usually has an HTTP status code of 201 ("Created"). Its `Location` header contains the URI of the newly created resource.

**PUT**

> The entity-body contains the client's proposed new representation of the resource. What data this is, and what format it's in, depends on the service.

**DELETE**

> The response entity-body may contain a status message or nothing at all

**HEAD**

> Retrieve a metadata-only representation.
> A client can use HEAD to check wheter a resource exists, or find out other information about the resource, without fetching its entire representation. HEAD gives you exactly what a GET request would give you, but without the entity-body

**OPTIONS**

> Contains the HTTP `Allow` header, which lays out the subset of the uniform interface this resource supports.